# Why is Async Await not working with Angular @Action

Tags: angular, ngxs

This works, but I would like to add more actions in a chain if possible.

```
this.store.dispatch(new UploadPendingFiles(pendingFiles));
this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(UploadPendingFiles)).subscribe(() => {
    alert('UploadPendingFilesComplete');
    this.store.dispatch(new CreateEmailLink(this.getPayload())).subscribe(
        () => {
            this.sent.emit('true');
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            this.errors$.next(error.messages);
        }
    );
});
```

Would like this style with using more async-await, but it fires things at the wrong times.

```
this.store.dispatch(new UploadPendingFiles(pendingFiles));
    alert('UploadPendingFilesComplete');
// Need alert to proc here
    await this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(UploadPendingFiles));
    // await Another @Action
    await this.store.dispatch(new CreateEmailLink(this.getPayload()));
// Alert procs here at the moment
```

A snippet of @Action

```
 @Action(UploadPendingFiles)
    uploadPendingFiles(ctx: StateContext<DriveStateModel>, action: UploadFiles) {
     return this.uploads.start(action.files, config).pipe(
            tap((response) => {
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `store.dispatch()` returns an `Observable` which completes on success. You can do the following:

```
this.store.dispatch(new UploadPendingFiles(pendingFiles)).pipe(
  concatMap(() => this.store.dispatch(new CreateEmailLink(this.getPayload()))
).subscribe(() => {
  // Alert procs here at the moment
});
```

Obviously you should also be able to use `.toPromise()`, but I suggest you do not go that way, as `Observables` are way more flexible. If you want to do promises, you can do the following:

```
async whatEverMethod(): Promise<any> {
  await this.store.dispatch(new UploadPendingFiles(pendingFiles)).toPromise();
  await this.store.dispatch(new CreateEmailLink(this.getPayload()).toPromise();

  //alert procs here at the moment
}
```

Comment: Kruijit Thank you for the great explanation and multiple solutions. I used your defer method and it works perfectly. I would like to use the toPromise(), but Im not sure what the difference is with losing flexibility. Ive tried reading the docs from ngxs but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I jumped the gun a bit, the defer didnt fire the send email, but the .toPromise() works, except I cant listen for the error. In the end I might have to restore it to the original,  doesn't look the best but at least it works. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Gavin I've removed my concat solution, that was the wrong operator. You should use `concatMap` for sequential Observables

Comment: I never knew that `ngxs` dispatch would return Observable. It makes more sense than `ngrx` dispatch / effects, there are too much boilerplate. I would migrate ngrx to ngxs one day, I think.

Comment: @HTN I didn't jump on the react/store bandwagon mainly because of the ngrx boilerplate, until ngxs came out, and everything was so much simpler/neater :)

Comment: @PoulKruijt I had no choice, I came to a project with ngrx and I spent days on reducing / removing ngrx effects boilerplate

Comment: Ok I managed to refactor, and I put the all the code into the module as an action, and I used concatMap() which works nice. Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

async/await is just a syntax to work with `Promise`. You can't use it with anything else like `Observable`, which is `action$`.

Waiting for the result of an action is kinda weird, it should be done with a `correlationId`, which make code even more complex. That's a reason why I don't feel like using Redux's Effect in theses situations.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I already have an existing codebase using @Action everywhere, I tried .toPromise() on the Action return but that failed too. Is the only way to just use subscribe with my current situation?